# Ubuntu One fails to launch from a terminal

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one

Ubuntu-one doesnt work on my Natty installation. It just fails to launch. Why?

I tried via terminal `ubuntuone-launch` - aborted, `sudo ubuntuone-launch` -no output. Why is this?

Comment: The question title is pretty vague.

Comment: @Thomas Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this is not working, but since upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04 the difficulty is with file syncing.  Personally this extends to other applications such as Nautilus and Rhythmbox.  I have been searching for possible solutions, but have not found anything that adequately addresses the issue.

**UPDATE:**

ROOT_MISMATCH in syncdaemon.log - This normally indicates that there may be two Ubuntu One accounts, one in the local cache and another setup in the keyring. This happens if the user installed Ubuntu One with one account and then sets up the computer again with a different account (but all the old Ubuntu One files in ~/.local/share/ubuntuone are still there under the old account). Working around this:

```
Open Applications->Accessories->Terminal and run:

  u1sdtool -q; killall ubuntuone-login ubuntuone-preferences;
  sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone
  rm -rf ~/.cache/ubuntuone
  rm -rf ~/.config/ubuntuone
  mv ~/Ubuntu\ One/ ~/Ubuntu\ One_old/ 

Open Applications->Accessories->Passwords and Encryption Keys, go to the Passwords tab, delete the Ubuntu One and Desktopcouch tokens by right-clicking on them and selecting "Delete"
Back in a terminal session, run:

  u1sdtool -q; killall ubuntuone-login; u1sdtool -c
```

To get things functioning again, all I had to do was delete my ~/.local/share/ubuntuone directory as indicated above.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Still wont work.


binoy@binoy-pc:~$ u1sdtool -q; killall ubuntuone-login; u1sdtool -c 
Aborted
ubuntuone-login: no process found
Aborted

Comment: Yeah, the u1sdtool command did nothing for me as well.  Instead it was the following command that worked its magic: **sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone**.  Then for good measure I did **rm -rf ~/.cache/ubuntuone** and **rm -rf ~/.config/ubuntuone**.  While Ubuntu One was immediately available after the first command, I did not that logging out and then back in seemed to fix the speed issue I was initially experiencing.  To date I have not had to do anything else and Ubuntu 11.04 is running flawlessly.